# RLock on udf function in Spark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, locking, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions

When we try to use udf function on select with RLock:

```
from ru.get_response_from_file_to_rest_proto_pb2 import GetPersonalDataResponseFromFileToRestProto


def bin_to_json(bin_value):
    deschifr = GetPersonalDataResponseFromFileToRestProto()

    try:
        decrypt_message = deschifr.FromString(bin_value)
    except DecodeError as e:
        logger.info(f"Decode error: {e}")
        raise e

    json_obj = MessageToJson(decrypt_message, ensure_ascii=True)

    return json_obj

bin_to_json_udf = functions.udf(lambda z: bin_to_json(z), StringType())


resultDF = resultDF.select(functions.monotonically_increasing_id().alias("uid"),
                           map_from_entries("headers").alias("headers_map"),
                           lit(load_id).alias("system_load_id"),
                           functions.current_timestamp().alias("update_timestamp"),
                           "*",
                           lit(None).cast(StringType()).alias("start_ltime"),
                           lit(False).alias("deleted_flag"),
                           functions.col("record_topic").alias("EntityAggregateName"),
                           bin_to_json_udf(functions.col("value")).alias("result_message")
                           )
```

we get the following error in Spark:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 774, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 890, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 549, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 662, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 504, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 859, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 885, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pickle.py", line 524, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

What may cause such a problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: A UDF not being serializable (or using non-serializable objects) is one possibility.